# React JS rendering wrong Lists and Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

Hi please I am stuck I have this code but it renders only numbers like the image below. What am I doing wrong.

```
       import useStats from '../utils/useStats';

export default function CountrySelector() {
    const countries = useStats('https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries');
    console.log(countries);
    if (!countries) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {Object.entries(countries.countries).map(([country, code]) => (
                    <option key={code} value={code}>
                        {country}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is what it outputs it need to list the country names.

[image]

Comment: May be changing from [country, code] to [ code, country]  solve your problem. Because the first value in Object.entries  array is the key while the second is the value

Comment: try console.log(Object.entries(countries.countries))

Answer (score 0):

The destructuring statement is wrongly created, see the following does the job:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Afghanistan","iso2":"AF","iso3":"AFG"},{"name":"Albania","iso2":"AL","iso3":"ALB"},{"name":"Algeria","iso2":"DZ","iso3":"DZA"},{"name":"Andorra","iso2":"AD","iso3":"AND"},{"name":"Angola","iso2":"AO","iso3":"AGO"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda","iso2":"AG","iso3":"ATG"},{"name":"Argentina","iso2":"AR","iso3":"ARG"}]

const result = data.map(({name, iso2: code}) => ({name, code}));

console.log(result);
```

So I would add as the following in your code:

```
<select>
    {countries.countries.map(({name, iso2: code}) => (
        <option key={code} value={code}>
            {name}
        </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by updating the jsx like:

```
{Object.entries(countries.countries).map(([idx, {name, iso2}]) => (
    <option key={iso2} value={iso2}>
        {name}
    </option>
))}
```

**Explanation:**

- `countries.countries` returns an array of objects.
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on array return array of `[index, value]` pairs, where `index` is the index of array and `value` is each object inside `countries` array.
- `[idx, {name, iso2}]` using this we will destructure the objects in the array and get only the `name` & `iso2` properties from it.
- and then we will display those values in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:

```
const App = () => {
const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);

React.useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios(
                "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/countries"
            );
            setState(result.data.countries);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };
    getData();
}, []);

console.log(state);

return (
    <div>    
            <select>
                {state &&
                    state.map(({ name, iso2, iso3 }) => (
                        <option key={name} value={name}>
                            {`${name} ${iso2} ${iso3}`}
                        </option>
                    ))}
            </select>            
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```